# How to illustrate user friendliness in an icon?

Tags: website-design, logo, icon, resource-recommendations, inspiration

I am building a web page for a software company, where I want to inform the visitor that our systems are user friendly, among other things. I would like an icon to go with that text. Do you have any idea what that icon would look like?
My first thought was a checkmark or a smiley, but they both feel boring. User friendly for me is really about minimizing friction or streamlining or something, but I don't know how to create an icon out of that. I'd be happy for all ideas.

Comment: Leave that space empty. Let the website show that you can make something which is easy to use and can be understood in the 1st glance.

Comment: "our systems are user friendly" Must not be reduced to one icon on a text, but in ALL the webpage design.

Comment: Have a look at [the noun project](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=user+friendly) for inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the most obvious icon will work best, but if you need some alternatives, head over to the Noun Project (no affiliation) and type any of the below in the search box. I am not listing specific icons, as you'll get plenty of results and we don't know enough here to pinpoint what you need exactly.

- meditation
- thumbs up
- check mark
- feather

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested about what I chose, here it is:

[image]